# One to one mapping by foreign key

Tags: hibernate

In Hibernate, when we try to achieve "One to one mapping by foreign key", does the foreign key need to be UNIQUE also (at table level)? 
If no, how does Hibernate ensure that one record in parent table is mapped to a unique foreign key (mapped to another entity ) ?

Suppose that I have a very simple one-to-one scenario to implement. One student has only one address and vice-versa.

```
student_table
id (pk),
name

address_table
id (pk),
desc,
stu_id (fk ==> references id of student_table)
```

In the above, do I have to put a UNIQUE constraint on the fk(stu_id) in my address_table ?

Or will Hibernate only stop me from duplicating foreign key in the address_table as below?

```
s = new student(1)
adress1 = new address
address1.set(s)
address1.save
```

and then...

```
address2 = new address
address2.set(s)  
address2.save ==== I m trying to set the same student in the new address..
So will Hibernate allow this ?
```

Comment: Yes, since the foreign key is the primary key in the foreign table, and the primary key, by definition should be unique

Comment: If, by any kind of situation, you have a non-unique relation, it cannot be `OneToOne`.